# Setting run-time parameters in SQL Kata

Tags: postgresql, sqlkata

Looking through the SQL Kata documentation I am unable to find an example of using SET to change a runtime parameter in Postgres.  Anyone know if this is even possible?

Comment: what about `db.Statement("any sql expression here")`

Comment: For the SQL expression, would the semi-colon go in there too?  And this line would go right before you use query.GetAsync?